# Simple Functions: Uniform Convergence

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral

*In the proof to proposition 4.2 of '[The Riemann Integral](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/chap4.pdf)' it is stated that the net of simple functions converges uniformly for continuous functions. This question aims to prove this in a general setting.*

Given a compact metric space: $X$
together with the Borel algebra: $\mathcal{B}(X)$
and a Banach space: $E$

Consider a continuous function: $f:X\to E$
and measurable (tagged) partitions: $\forall A\in\pi:\quad A\in\mathcal{B}(X)$
together with simple functions: $f_\pi:=\sum_{A\in\pi} f(a)\mathbb{1}_{A}\quad a\in A$

Then the net of simple functions converges uniformly:
$$\lim_{\pi}\|f_\pi-f\|_\infty=0$$
where the order on partitions is given by:
$$\pi'\geq\pi:\iff \forall A'\in\pi'\exists A\in\pi: A'\subseteq A$$

Can somebody help me proving this?

Comment: What is the ordering of this net?

Comment: Depends on how general the statement still holds true but for those ones where the space itself has finite measure then the partitions should be ordered by refinement (as used for filters too): $\pi\leq\pi':\iff \pi\dashv\pi'$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By local continuity there is a delta for any point:
$$d(x,z)<\delta(z)\implies d(f(x),f(z))<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$$
By compactness there is a finite cover:
$$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^N B_{\delta(z_i)}(z_i)$$
Choose the partition:
$$\pi_\epsilon:\quad A_n:=B_{\delta(z_n)}(z_n)\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} B_{\delta(z_i)}(z_i)$$
Then for any subpartition:
$$\pi\geq\pi_\epsilon:\quad \|s_\pi(x)-f(x)\|\leq\|s_\pi(x)-f(z_{i_0})\|+\|f(x)-f(z_{i_0})\|<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon=\epsilon$$

*Note that uniform continuity was not required!*